# PHP delete cookie issue

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting a cookie as follows:

```
if($persist=='persist'){ //  if remember me then set long cookie expiration

        setcookie("aukCookie", "$user", time()+9900000, "/", "myurl.com");
        setcookie("aukCookie2", "$username", time()+9900000, "/", "myurl.com");
        setcookie("AUKpersist", "$user", 0, "/", "myurl.com");

    } else {

        setcookie("aukCookie", "$user", time()+86400, "/", "myurl.com");
        setcookie("aukCookie2", "$username", time()+9900000, "/", "myurl.com");

    }
```

Then to delete I go to the same file with url variable `?logoff=true`

Then I try the following:

```
if ($_GET[logoff]=='true'){
    setcookie ("aukCookie", "", time()-3600, "/", "myurl.com"); 
    setcookie ("AUKpersist", "", time()-3600, "/", "myurl.com"); 
    // use below to send user somewhere when logged out successfully
    header("Location: /userAdmin/userlogin.html?loggedOut"); 
}
```

But the cookie is simply not being deleted. The `header()` function works fine.

Any ideas? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is `header` called before sending page data? That's the most likely explanation

Comment: you need use `cookie`? maybe `session`?

Answer (score 2):

try setting null instead of empty, like:

```
if ($_GET[logoff]=='true'){
    setcookie ("aukCookie", NULL, time()-3600, "/", "myurl.com"); 
    setcookie ("AUKpersist", NULL, time()-3600, "/", "myurl.com"); 
    // use below to send user somewhere when logged out successfully
    header("Location: /userAdmin/userlogin.html?loggedOut"); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this if condition is working? I mean is $_GET[logoff] returning true?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with `unset`

i.e.,

```
unset($_COOKIE["aukCookie"]);
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setcookie("aukCookie", "", -1, "/", "myurl.com");
```

Answer (score -1):

To delete cookies

**bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )**

`setcookie ("mycookiename", "", time() - 3600);`

another example

`setcookie("mycookiename", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);`

Test it

```
enter code here // Print an individual cookie
```

`enter code here echo $_COOKIE["mycookiename"];`
`echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["mycookiename"];`

`// Another way to debug/test is to view all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);`
this is the set cookies concept

In case of **logOff** you need to **unset** the cookies like below example

`unset($_COOKIE['mycookiename']);`

Something like this

if ($_GET[logoff]=='true'){

unset($_COOKIE['aukCookie']);

unset($_COOKIE['AUKpersist']);

header("Location: /userAdmin/userlogin.html?loggedOut");

}